# How can I plot two linear regressions on one same graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I used `stat_poly_eq` to plot the linear regression equation for the dataset of two years. Now I want to draw the two equations in the same graph.

Here is the original dataset:

```
df<-structure(list(Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), Variety = c("Sultana - MG 000", 
"ES Pallador - MG I", "Isidor - MG I", "Santana - MG I/II", "Blancas - MG II", 
"Ecudor - MG II", "Sultana - MG 000", "ES Pallador - MG I", "Isidor - MG I", 
"Santana - MG I/II", "Blancas - MG II", "Ecudor - MG II"), FTSWt = c(0.91, 
0.79, 0.92, 0.48, 0.51, 0.46, 0.93, 0.59, 0.58, 0.44, 0.48, 0.52
), SLA = c(85.38, 111.94, 108.56, 120.54, 130.14, 123.25, 109.05, 
149.97, 168.64, 162.96, 140.18, 175.1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Here is my original data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library("RColorBrewer")
library(stats)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(df,aes(y=FTSWt,x=SLA))+
geom_point(aes(color= Variety),size=3)+
geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x,se=FALSE,color="black") +
stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.85,
               formula = y ~ x, parse = TRUE, size = 4)+
geom_text_repel(aes(label=Variety,color=Variety))+
scale_color_manual(values = c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3","#FF7F00","#A65628","#A65628"))+
labs(y = "SLA", x = "FTSWt")+
theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,vjust=0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=13),
        legend.text=element_text(size=11),
        legend.position = "none")+
facet_wrap(~Year)
```

Here is the graph that I got:
[image]

Now I want to combine these two graphs into one graph. Two types of lines with two corresponding equations (distinguished by color).

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you in adavance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `group` aesthetic and proceed as intended like so:

```
ggplot(aes(FTSWt, SLA, group = Year)) +
   ## rest of ggplot stuff
```

(don't forget to remove the trailing `facet_wrap`)

Comment: Hi I have one more question: the positions of two equations are overlapped. How can I solve it?

Comment: `stat_poly_eq` accepts multiple position values, e. g.:`label.y.npc = c(0.8, 0.85)`